# How to make the object go from point A to point B

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want the object to reach object A, then to object B, then to object C and back to object A. I’ve been using the `Lerp` function, but I didn’t get anything, just the object itself disappeared. And I also tried to create empty objects and set the conditions for the object to move but it also didn’t come out of the fact that the object reached 1 point but continued to move

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do this.transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(pos1, pos2, timeFraction)

Please refer to this on how to use your Lerp method correctly. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html